# Unable to edit PostgreSQL/PostGIS layers in ArcMap using query layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcgis-10.2, editing, query-layer

I am connected to the database, have added a layer, started edit session, but I am unable to edit the attributeeo table of said layer.  ArcMap 10.2.2 tells me that it is not an editable layer.  When attempting the same procedure in QGIS, I am able to make any edits I need to.

Does the database need to be modified to allow specific users read/write ability?

Comment: Have you switched off the versioned editing for your Editor options? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000s8000000. Also good if you add a screenshot of the error message you get.

Comment: Are you loading layers as Query layers, or do you have ArcSDE ArcGIS Server installed using Postgresql as the backend?

Comment: The warning says, The workspace containing this data cannot be edited.  I switched the versioned editing off, but resulted in same warning.  We are loading layers as query layers...

Comment: Not entirely surprising, since Query Layers are read-only.  http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2014/04/08/the-evolution-of-query-layers/

Comment: Please update question to specify ArcGIS release ( **10** .2.2?)

Comment: Version 10.2.2  That link is extremely helpful.  Thanks Vince.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince your lack of success when trying to edit via query layers is:

> Not entirely surprising, since Query Layers are read-only. 
>   http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2014/04/08/the-evolution-of-query-layers/